# Cannot transfer value from JQuery date range picker to input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a basic JQuery date range picker from this example site: http://www.daterangepicker.com/. I am looking for a way to take the provided output from the date range picker and place them into two inputs fields after the dates have been selected. For now, I just want to prove that I can display each value in the new input fields. In the future, I will parse the string to provide two separate dates, but please ignore this for now.

```
<input id="dateRangePicker" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField2" />
```

This is what I've tried so far:

**Script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(function () {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dateRangePicker').on('change', function () {
                $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(this.value);
                $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(this.value);
            }).change();
            $('#dateRangePicker').on('daterangepicker', function (e, ui) {
                $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(ui.item.value);
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

How can I move the value from the date range picker to each of the input fields?

Comment: why have you added .change() in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **on('apply.daterangepicker')** to get date pickers startDate and endDate values to input fields.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));         
    $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(function () {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dateRangePicker').on('change', function () {
    $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(this.value);
    $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(this.value);
  }).change();
  $('#dateRangePicker').on('daterangepicker', function (e, ui) {
    $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(ui.item.value);
    $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(ui.item.value);
  });
});

$('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));     $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<input id="dateRangePicker" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField2" />
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/derfekse/

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this using `daterangepicker` *onselect function*. Please follow below code::

**HTML**

```
<input id="dateRangePicker" type="text" name="daterange" value="" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField" /><br />
<input id="selectedDatePickerField2" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#dateRangePicker').daterangepicker({}, function(start, end, label) {
        $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That component has two properties to report the `startDate` and the `endDate` selected. You need to read those properties after the change event is generated. To access those properties this is the syntax:

var drp = $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').xxxxxx;

where xxxx is the method you want to call (it could be a method or a property)

Date Range Picker documentation:

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

```
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();


    $('#dateRangePicker').on('change', function () 
    {
        $('#selectedDatePickerField').val($('#dateRangePicker').data('daterangepicker').startDate);
        $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val($('#dateRangePicker').data('daterangepicker').endDate);
    });

    $('#dateRangePicker').on('daterangepicker', function (e, ui) 
    {
        $('#selectedDatePickerField').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#selectedDatePickerField2').val(ui.item.value);
    });
```

if you want to set the start date after initialized you can use:

```
//change the selected date range of that picker
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('03/01/2014');
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('03/31/2014');
```

and finally a fiddle that shows how all goes together:

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/oj8yhnLo/1/

Hope it helps!